# Split string into "n" lengths with padding

Tags: c++, performance, strings, parsing, cryptography

I quickly wrote a short program to split a string into \$n\$ lengths with variable-character padding:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string getString();
int getBlockSize();
char getPaddingChar();
std::string addPadding(std::string str, int blockSize, char paddingChar);
std::string tokenize(std::string str, int blockSize);

int main(){
    std::string str = getString();
    int blockSize = getBlockSize();
    char paddingChar = getPaddingChar();

    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());
    str = addPadding(str, blockSize, paddingChar);
    str = tokenize(str, blockSize);

    std::cout << str;

    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}

std::string getString(){
    std::cout << "Input string: ";

    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    return str;
}

int getBlockSize(){
    std::string inputStr;
    int blockSize;

    do{
        try{
            std::cout << "Block size: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, inputStr);
            blockSize = std::stoi(inputStr);
        } catch(...){
            blockSize = 0;
        }
    } while(blockSize < 1);

    return blockSize;
}

char getPaddingChar(){
    char paddingChar;

    do{
        std::cout << "Padding character: ";
        std::cin >> paddingChar;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    } while(std::cin.fail());

    return paddingChar;
}

std::string addPadding(std::string str, int blockSize, char paddingChar){
    while(str.length() % blockSize != 0){
        str += paddingChar;
    }
    return str;
}

std::string tokenize(std::string str, int blockSize){
    for(int i = blockSize; i < str.length(); i += blockSize+1){     
        str.insert(i, 1, ' ');
    }
    return str;
}
```

This code firstly gets the input string (`str`), gets the size of the block (`blockSize`), and then gets the character that is to be used as padding (`paddingChar`).

It then removes all spaces from input string, adds padding, and then tokenizes the string by splitting it into `blockSize` pieces.

Example output:

```
Input string: Tis' but a scratch!
Block size: 11
Padding character: X
Tis'butascr atch!XXXXXX
```

The splitting of a stream of characters into blocks is [common in cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher). While there certainly are [many, many Code Review questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=tokenize) on tokenization, I was unable to find one that was exactly like this and in C++, so I felt that this area should also be covered in that aspect.

I tried to use the helpful suggestions from my previous Code Review questions to improve the quality of my code as best I could. Despite that, there is always room to improve the way that I write code.

How can I improve this code?

Comment: isn't this algorithm lossy? i.e. how do you recover the original plaintext?

Comment: @RichardHodges The message is still decipherable by a human, i.e. you can still tell that the message `Tis'butascr atch!XXXXXX` is meaning `Tis' but a scratch!`. This type of classical cryptography is mainly used as a first step before something like [columnar transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher#Columnar_transposition). But you're right, it isn't meant for a computer to recover the plaintext, that would be much harder.

Answer (score 2):

My first impression is that we would probably wish to avoid copying and shuffle data as much as possible.

The code as presented does the following:

1. conditionally remove items (worst case time complexity occurs when every char is a space, in which case it's \$\mathcal{O}(\frac{n^2}{2})\$ (more or less))
2. append padding (worst case will involve a reallocation plus copy \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$)

I think we can do better, performing the entire operation in linear time and guaranteeing no memory reallocations. This involves iteratively conditionally copying the bytes. We can do this because std::string's iterators are random-access, so we can compute distances in constant time.

I have presented it here as a simple composition of methods in a lightweight engine object. Another way would be to create a state machine which could be chained to another encryption stage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct squish_engine
{
    squish_engine(std::size_t blockSize, char paddingChar)
            : blockSize(blockSize)
            , paddingChar(paddingChar)
    {

    }

    // useful for initial allocation of destination string
    std::size_t estimate_size(std::size_t plaintext_length) const {
        return plaintext_length + blockSize;
    }

    // a predicate    
    static bool matchesSpace(char c) {
        return c == ' ';
    }

    // operation in terms of iterators    
    template<class FromIter, class ToIter>
    ToIter operator()(FromIter first, FromIter last, ToIter first2) const
    {
        // use stl algorithms where possible
        auto last2 = std::remove_copy_if(first, last, first2, matchesSpace);
        auto pads = std::distance(first2, last2) % blockSize;
        if (pads) {
            pads = blockSize - pads;
        }
        last2 += pads;
        return last2;
    };

    // this is the public interface    
    template<class Iter>
    std::string operator()(Iter first, Iter last) const
    {
        // build an overly-large string to accept the result.
        // we may as well pad it now, as it's no extra cost compared
        // to zero-filling
        std::string result(estimate_size(std::distance(first, last)), paddingChar);
        // our internal operator will compute the end point of the
        // padded area for us
        auto last2 = (*this)(first, last, std::begin(result));

        // so we can simply truncate any padding chars we don't need
        result.erase(last2, result.end());

        // and return the cypher
        return result;
    }

    // convenience interface
    std::string operator()(const std::string& s)
    {
        return (*this)(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
    }

    std::size_t blockSize;
    char paddingChar;
};

// the concept of making a copy while filtering
template<class Filter>
std::string filter_copy(const std::string& source, Filter&& filter)
{
    return filter(source);
}

int main(){

    std::size_t blockSize = 11;
    char paddingChar = 'X';

    std::string str = "Tis' but a scratch!";

    // now we can conceivably choose the encryption engine at the
    // client call site
    auto compressed = filter_copy(str, squish_engine(blockSize, paddingChar));

    std::cout << compressed << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```